# Recursive evenness check returns undefined

Tags: javascript

There is [an exercise in *Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_iDq2OgBOGw) whose wording is:

> #### Recursion
>
> We’ve seen that `%` (the remainder operator) can be used to test whether
>   a number is even or odd by using `% 2` to check whether it’s divisible by
>   two. Here’s another way to define whether a positive whole number is
>   even or odd:
>
> - Zero is even.
> - One is odd.
> - For any other number N, its evenness is the same as N - 2.
>
> Define a recursive function `isEven` corresponding to this description. The
>   function should accept a number parameter and return a Boolean.
>
> Test it on 50 and 75. See how it behaves on -1. Why? Can you think
>   of a way to fix this?

They provide a solution, and I’ve already written a working implementation, but another always returns `undefined`; why is this?

```
var isEven = function ( a ) {
    var r = false;
    if ( a === 0 || a === 1 ) {
        a === 0 ? r = true : r ;
        return r;
    } else
        a < 0 ? isEven(-1 * a) : isEven(a - 2);
};

console.log(isEven(50));
```

When the number is not 0 or 1, the `else` branch seems to work fine; the problem, I think, is in the `if` branch.

Comment: Using recursion for this is like using a nuclear bomb instead of a fly-swatter to kill a fly

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, I was shocked by number of answers in that relatively short time :)

Comment: This is like the javascript version of a Rube Goldberg machine...

Comment: Please, I'm trying to learn and I've tried to work it out by myself before posting. Why do I get negative punctuation?

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 You're getting downvotes because the question is technically 'off-topic', given that the problem was a simple typo; we're just following protocol.  I assure you, we do not mean it as a personal slight.  In fact, I think most of us find your creative implementation of this function pretty entertaining.

Comment: This is the third account I have to use to log into StackOverflow. The two previous ones are not allowed to post anymore. I'm trying to learn to do not repeat same fails but let me tell you that is absolutely not polite to kick me in my noob bottom and not explaining me why did you stab me. And this is not a problem of mine. The problem is that in this world, the world of computer science, some people use to look down on you because your knowledge is not good enough. Is not the first time this happen to me both Internet and real life. So, thank you very much to those people who voted me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `return` statement in the else branch. As it is you're just evaluating the expression and discarding the result.

Comment: I thought that else-branch would use the return of the base case. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
a < 0 ? isEven(-1 * a) : isEven( a-2);
```

This line is missing a `return`. So you could write it this way:

```
var isEven = function ( a ) {
    var r = false;
    if ( a === 0 || a === 1 ) {
        a === 0 ? r = true : r ;
        return r;
    }else 
        return a < 0 ? isEven(-1 * a) : isEven( a-2);
}
```

But this way works too:

```
function isEven(a) {
    return a % 2 === 0;
}
```

You can expand that to use recursion without making things as complicated, e.g.

```
function isEven(a) {
    return (
        a === 0 ? true       :
        a === 1 ? false      :
        a < 0   ? isEven(-a) : isEven(a - 2));
}
```

because setting `r = true` in a `?` operator isn’t actually functional, if that was the point. I’d still use the operator, though, since it works on ±Infinity and NaN.

Comment: yeah, I know that it's easier with operator `%`, I edited the question explaining why I did it in that way.
I didn't know you could use the return and the ternary operator like this. I thought that else-branch would use the return of the base case. Thanks

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 The `;` and `}` should both be good indicators that the return statement is being closed and will not apply to anything further.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I think know I understand better how recursion works with programming languages. Thanks

Comment: +1 for the detailed examples. I also had trouble with this exercise by not `return`ing the recursive function call. Once `return`ed all was good.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you are not using a simple even odd check?

```
var isEven = function ( a ) {
    return (a % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: That’s not simple; `return a % 2 === 0;` is simple. =)

Comment: You are right, I wanted to write it out so the OP understands whats going on

Comment: @Noob_Number_1 whoever wrote that exercise needs to go back to programming 101

Comment: The exercise can be found here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/. And as far as I know, is one of the best books at JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers I got what is going wrong.

In a recursive case, if you want to pass the result of the base case to the calls which are waiting for a response, is essential using `result`, anyway nothing will do it. If the call of the case base end without any result, what do you expect to happen? Nothing is returned and so on.

Another thing I learnt is that you cannot use the `result` with the ternary operator.

So, finally, one solution can be this one:

```
var isEven = function ( a ) {
    var r = false;
    if ( a === 0 || a === 1 ) {
        a === 0 ? r = true : r ;
        return r;
    }else if ( a < 0)
        return isEven(-a);
    else
        return isEven(a-2);
}
```

which works perfectly.

If anyone wants to know the solution provided by the book, is this one:

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
```

}

Comment: Where you have `a === 0 ? r = true : r; return r;`, it could be simpler to use `return a === 0;`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm typical guy who wrote in 100 lines what can be done in just 5 :D